# Issue with variable being undefined

Tags: jquery, scope

I've created a function that loops through a set of products, and sets the height of their copy area to the height of the tallest copy area in that set.

Here's my code:

```
function productCopyHeight(){
    //make sub range product text sections the same height
    if($('.sub-range').length){
        $('.sub-range').each(function(){
            var itemHeight = 0;
            $(this).children('.product-item').children('.copy').each(function(i){
                var thisItemHeight = $(this).height();
                console.log(thisItemHeight + ' > ' + itemHeight)

                if(thisItemHeight > itemHeight){
                    var itemHeight = thisItemHeight;
                }

            });
            $(this).children('.product-item').children('.copy').css('height', itemHeight);
        })
    }

}
```

When I log it it shows the itemHeight variable as undefined when it is defined before the each loop.

Comment: What line is it saying that `itemHeight` is undefined?

Comment: And what is the output of the `console.log`?

Comment: The console output is '44 > undefined'

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are declaring another variable by the same name inside the callback for the inner `each`. Here:

```
if(thisItemHeight > itemHeight){
  var itemHeight = thisItemHeight;
}
```

That variable is different from the variable before the loop, and that variable is also hoisted to the top of the function. The variable has the value `undefined` because you use it before you assign a value to it.

You should use the variable that you already have instead of creating another one:

```
if(thisItemHeight > itemHeight){
  itemHeight = thisItemHeight;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it is very obvious now I have the answer, facepalm. Though now the console is outputting '22 > 0, 44 > 22, 44 > 0'

Comment: @Forxs: That looks correct if you have two iterations in the outer loop. What result did you expect?

Comment: Ignore that, it's just poor logic now - the variable needs to be set before the previous .each. Thanks for your help